# BoxShadow is drew above other widgets

Tags: flutter, shadow

I'm trying to make glow around items in list. For this I use box-shadow in item's decoration. But it is appeared above other items, not as background. How to draw boxshadow behind sibling items as well.

```
class ShadowItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const ShadowItem({required this.isWithGlow});

  final bool isWithGlow;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 100,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        boxShadow: (isWithGlow)
            ? [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  blurRadius: 42.0,
                  spreadRadius: 0.0,
                  offset: Offset(
                    0.0,
                    12.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ]
            : [],
      ),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(19),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

you need to set margins between boxes so the shadow will not overflow on another widget.
[image]
I am using **flutter_neumorphic: ^3.0.3** Package to solve your problem.

here is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_neumorphic/flutter_neumorphic.dart';

class ShadowItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const ShadowItem({required this.isWithGlow});

  final bool isWithGlow;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      height: 100,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 5),
      child: Neumorphic(
        style: isWithGlow
            ? NeumorphicStyle(
            shadowDarkColor: Colors.blue,
            shadowLightColor: Colors.blue,
            depth: 10,
            shape: NeumorphicShape.convex,
            lightSource: LightSource.right)
            : NeumorphicStyle(
          depth: 2,
          shape: NeumorphicShape.convex,
        ),
        child: Container(
         
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(19),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Off course, adding margin can help, but it is not proper solution and I have to implement design without such big margin.

Comment: You can check it without margins.

Comment: Sure, I've already checked it without margins and it still overlaps other widgets. I played with Box Shadow params (radiuses and offset) and reach some similar results with requirements.

Comment: The actual problem in the widget is the margin. suppose you give (20) box-shadow value to a widget then you must need a margin with the same value if a single widget or half of it if in a listview. if not! your shadow will overlap with another widget.

Comment: and more your shadow is meaningless if there is no margin-space to show it

Answer (score -1):

Your need is to show `BoxShadow` depends on the isWithGlow. so you can set grey shadow background instead of empty shadow `[]` and set margin for container, it will highlight your Container.

```
return Container(
   height: 100,
   margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
     boxShadow: (isWithGlow)
         ? [
             BoxShadow(
               color: Colors.blue,
               blurRadius: 42.0,
               spreadRadius: 0.0,
               offset: Offset(
                 0.0,
                 12.0,
               ),
              ),
             ]
           : [
              BoxShadow(
                 color: Colors.grey[400]!,
                 blurRadius: 42.0,
                 spreadRadius: 0.0,
                 offset: Offset(
                   0.0,
                   12.0,
                 ),
               ),
             ],  
           ),
           child: Container(
             decoration: BoxDecoration(
               color: Colors.white,
               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(19),
           ),
          ),
        );
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Adding margin is not a solution, because I have to implement design without such big margin.